# On Windows Linux Subsystem, the Android SDK directory does not exist

Tags: android, linux, windows, ubuntu, react-native

I have been running `react native` for a while on `windows 10` but decided to install the `ubuntu subsystem` to continue my development as I prefer linux for dev work.

After installing `ubuntu` and trying to build my `react native` app I get this error.

> The SDK directory
>   /mnt/c/Projects/AppName/android/C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'
>   does not exist.

The path is strange looking as it has my current path concatenated with the actual location of my android sdk on my windows file system (but not the path linux needs as it uses `/mnt/c/` instead of `C:\`). That looks pretty wrong.

Here's some info about my system:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME 
/mnt/c/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/

less android/local.properties
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

It seems like you should be able to link to the Windows install of the android sdk, if it used my `ANDROID_HOME` I think it would work. But something tells me I might need to install the sdk separately on ubuntu. I'd like to avoid that for hard disk space reasons.

I'm hoping to be able to keep react native working on windows and in the ubuntu subsystem if possible as I'm not sure if there will be some issue in the future for running react native on ubuntu. It currently works great on windows 10 so... not trying to break that.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `local.properties` file should use a Linux path instead:

```
# sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
sdk.dir=/mnt/c/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
```

and when switching the OS, just added the `#` to the other one line.

Answer (score 1):

I edited `~/.profile` to have this line:

```
export $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/mnt/c/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
```